# Testing promise value returned by service

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

**How can I test the value of a promise, returned by a service?** In the [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), the promise value is preset in the test using resolve(value). Other approaches test the service logic in a controller, using the fact that AngularJS evaluates the promises and binds the values the $scope.

In my opinion, none of these approaches actually test the logic of the service in the place where it should be tested. How can I test that the resolved promise (which is returned by the service) contains the correct value?

Here an example:

```
myApp.service('service', function($q){
    var obj = {};
    obj.test = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(false);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return obj;
});
```

In order to test the service, I want to do the following in theory (which does not work in practice):
    var $q, service;

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule');
    service = $injector.get('service');
});

describe('...', function() {
    it('Testing whether promise contains correct value', function() {
       var myPromise = service.test();
       myPromise.then(function(value) {
           expect(value).toBeFalsy();
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are injecting the service in a wrong way. You have to use the underscore notation. Please refer this link. http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/12/unit-testing-services-in-angularjs-for-fun-and-for-profit/

So, your test should look something like this.

```
var service;    
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myModule');
    inject(function(_service_) {
        service = _service_;
    });
});


describe('...', function() {
    it('Testing whether promise contains correct value', function() {
        var myPromise = service.test();
        myPromise.then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toBeFalsy();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree that I should be returning a promise (changed it in the original question), but this still does not make it work.

Comment: can you post other parts of your test particularly to the part where you setup the tests?